# How to detect that the cursor hovers an element without moving it?

Tags: javascript, react-router, mouseevent, mouseover

I’m building a web app where the pages have previous/next navigation buttons. It’s a single-page React application and the data for the previous or next page is prefetched when the navigation buttons are hovered.

When the user clicks “next” twice without moving the mouse, the data for the third page isn’t preloaded although the mouse keeps hovering the button (which is on the same position on each page), because the `mouseover` event doesn’t fire until and unless the mouse is moved at least 1px after each page load.

Is there a way to detect the mouseover event without moving the cursor, that doesn’t involve manually checking the dimensions of the button in particular via `getBoundingClientRects()` and comparing with the cursor `clientX`/`clientY` coordinates on page load?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could keep the state of mouseover in your React state, and toggle it using mounseenter and mouseleave.

Comment: `mouseover` to set `let currently_active_button` to the hovered button. `mouseout` to reset that it back to null. That way you always known which the last `mouseover`ed button was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As both jalynn2 and Shilly recommended, it's probably best to store this property in state as a boolean `true` on `onMouseEnter` and vice versa when `onMouseLeave`